# Adding cache to django couses ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI error

Tags: python, django

I'm following the official Django documentation. I added this to my settings.py

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
    }
}
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ALIAS = 'default'
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS  = '900'  # 15 minutes
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX = ''

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
]
```

And this somehow causes this error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application 'online_store.wsgi.applicati
on' could not be loaded; Error importing module
```

Have anybody ever dealt with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, never mind. Django's documentation did't say to `pip install python-memcached`, so I didn't. That was the problem.